# Which DBMS should I use for 1000s of columns and no joins?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture, nosql

We have a table design that consists of `10,000,000` records and `200,000` columns.

The columns are a mixture of:

- Binary flags.
- Integers.

The queries need to perform `and` / `or` operations on `1-100` columns at a time, and should complete in under `0.1` seconds, returning a only projection/subset of each matched row.

Around `10` new columns get added per day.

Around `1,000` new rows get added per day.

There are no joins.

Which DBMS is best suited for this?

**Reason behind this approach:**
The columns are materialized indexes from user defined queries: that's why new columns get added each day (as more users come up with their own queries). The other option would be to not use materialized views, and have the user's queries perform joins. Problem here is the queries could take any form and in aggregate there would be a large number of very different execution plans across everyones query... since the user defines the query, it's kinda impossible to optimise a traditional SQL database using indexes, normalised tables, etc.

Comment: Sounds like one of the worst designs ever. Can you tell us why you need 200 000 columns?!?

Comment: Putting aside whether you can make JOINs themselves fast enough... Why do you need to put everything in the same table? Can't you materialize each query separately?

Comment: Yes, that's a good option. This means we'd instead have a table for each query type (if I understand you correctly). At this moment in time I can't say whether we have more query types or more columns... but it's quite likely we'd have ~100,000 tables with this approach.

Comment: isn't that a question for Database Administrators? I think there your question is placed best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, I'd suggest measuring ad-hoc JOINs, and only doing further optimization if you find the performance lacking. I understand it could be difficult to measure every possible query, but you may be able to cover most common/representative cases, and if they perform well-enough just stop there. There is a lot that can be done with [good indexing](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning)!

**Second**, and only if the measurements above warrant it, create a new separate materialized view for each ad-hoc query.

- Some databases will be able to maintain such views automatically for you<sup>1</sup>, so if the "base" data changes, relevant results will be automatically added or removed from the materialized view (just as they would from the "live" query result).
- Other databases may allow periodic refresh<sup>2</sup>.

Be warned though: maintaining materialized views is not free, and having thousands of them (especially if they are constantly kept up-to-date, as opposed to periodically refreshed) will definitely impact the insert/update/delete performance on the base data!

---

*<sup>1</sup> E.g. SQL Server indexed views.*

*<sup>2</sup> E.g. Oracle Materialized views, although it looks like 12c can also do something close to SQL Server's immediate refresh.*

Answer (score 1):

Keeping aside ,why you want to go with 1000 of columns,you can look at below databases which support,unlimited columns

[image]

References:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems